# Eclipse Jetty v8.0 JNDI DataSource not available in scala lift application

Tags: scala, jetty, lift, sbt

I use xsbt v.0.10.1, web plugin for it, lift v2.4-M4, Scala 2.9.1, Jetty 8.0.0.v20110901.

In Boot.scala i add such code:

```
DefaultConnectionIdentifier.jndiName = "jdbc/db"
logger.warn("JNDI connection availbale ? " + DB.jndiJdbcConnAvailable_?)
```

And in jetty logs i see:

```
08:39:06.562 [Scanner-0] WARN  bootstrap.liftweb.Boot - JNDI connection availbale ? false
```

I use web.xml v2.5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>LiftFilter</filter-name>
        <display-name>Lift Filter</display-name>
        <description>The Filter that intercepts lift calls</description>
        <filter-class>net.liftweb.http.LiftFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>My DataSource Reference</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/db</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LiftFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And my context.xml for my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<!-- ==================================================================
Configure and deploy the test web application in $(jetty.home)/webapps/test

Note. If this file did not exist or used a context path other that /test
then the default configuration of jetty.xml would discover the test
webapplication with a WebAppDeployer.  By specifying a context in this
directory, additional configuration may be specified and hot deployments 
detected.
===================================================================== -->

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Array id="plusConfig" type="java.lang.String">
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item> <!-- add -->
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>    <!-- add -->
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration</Item>
  </Array>

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- Required minimal context configuration :                        -->
  <!--  + contextPath                                                  -->
  <!--  + war OR resourceBase                                          -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/test.war</Set>
  <Set name="configurationClasses"><Ref id="plusConfig"/></Set>

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- Optional context configuration                                  -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
  <Set name="copyWebDir">false</Set>


   <New id="ds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/db</Arg>
    <Arg>
     <New class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
                 <Set name="driverClass">org.h2.Driver</Set>
                 <Set name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:h2:~/test</Set>
                 <Set name="username">sa</Set>
                 <Set name="password">sa</Set>
     </New>
    </Arg>
   </New>

</Configure>
```

I try a simple java application with check JNDI availability and it works, seems problem in sbt.

Maybe someone already had such problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug of Lift v2.4-M4

This at begining of Boot.scala:

```
DefaultConnectionIdentifier.jndiName = "jdbc/db"
logger.warn("JNDI connection available (manyally) ? " + (((new InitialContext).lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/db").asInstanceOf[DataSource]) != null))
logger.warn("JNDI connection available (lift) ? " + DB.jndiJdbcConnAvailable_?)
```

Prints:

```
16:43:52.937 [main] WARN  bootstrap.liftweb.Boot - JNDI connection available (manyally) ? true
16:43:53.015 [main] WARN  bootstrap.liftweb.Boot - JNDI connection available (lift) ? false
```

As a temp workaround i implement ConnectionManager and add to DB.defineConnectionManager.